# using PHP to display data from database using a dropdown list

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to display data from database using PHP, based on the code from http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp .
Instead of using the ID column, I am using the TITLE column in my lecture table and it's not working. Nothing is being displayed(no warnings, no nothing).
How can I make this work? Here are my codes

```
<script>
    function showReport2(str)
    {
        if (str=="")
        {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
            return;
        } 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {   // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {   // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","LectureReport.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>
```

My HTML

```
<!-- lectures combo-->
<label for = "LectTitle">
<span>Select Lecture:</span>
&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp
<select name="lectures" onchange="showReport2(this.value)">
    <option value="">----Select Lecture----</option>
    <option value="1">Accounts</option>
    <option value="Web Design">Web Design</option>
    <option value="Database Administration">Database Administration</option>
    <option value="Mathematics">Mathematics</option>
    <option value="English">English</option>
    <option value="French">French</option>
    <option value="Mobile Device">Mobile Device</option>
</select>
</label>

<br/>
<hr>

<div id="txtHint">
    <center>
        Reports Will be displayed here
    </center>
</div>
```

My PHP script

```
<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','ewsd_coursework_db');
if (!$connect)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($connect));
}


$sql="
    SELECT 
        * 
    FROM 
        lecture 
    WHERE 
        LECTURE_NUMBER = '".$q."'
    ";

$result = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);

echo "
<table border='1'>
<tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Overview</th>
    <th>Room</th>
    <th>Organiser</th>
    <th>Presenter</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Time</th>
</tr>
";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['TITLE'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['OVERVIEW'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['ROOM'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['ORGANISER'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['PRESENTER'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['DATE'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['TIME'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($connect);
?>
```

Comment: Use var_dump($row) in while loop and  check what value is coming in that.

Comment: You are forcing $q to be an integer with this `$q = intval($_GET['q']);`. It would help if we could know few lines from DB. So for anything else than Accounts that value is 0.

Comment: And you have to use PDO. Just you have to.

Comment: am getting  Notice: Undefined variable: row in C:\wamp\www\esd_site\LectureReport.php on line 25 and "null" below that

Comment: this is my insert statement "INSERT INTO `lecture` (`LECTURE_NUMBER`, `TITLE`, `OVERVIEW`, `ROOM`, `ORGANISER`, `PRESENTER`, `DATE`, `TIME`) VALUES
(1, 'Accounts', 'accounting course', 'R01', 'S01', 'S02', '2014-04-15', '08:30:00'),
(4, 'Web Design', 'blabla', 'R01', 'jess', 'mwale', '2014-04-23', '13:00:00'),
(5, 'Mathematics', 'lhklh', 'R01', 'jess', 'mwale', '2014-04-24', '00:59:00');"

Comment: Note that you are still using lecture number for SQL select. Due that only Accounts search should return item(s). Try calling directly the `LectureReport.php?q=1`. There should start your debugging. Do you get anything back? If you do, your problem lies in javascript.

Comment: changed $q = intval($_GET['q']); to $q =($_GET['q']);  and it works! thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
while($row = $result->fetch_array())
{
```